# wait() isn't interrupted by notifyAll()

Tags: java

I've made the following code sample, which tests `wait()` and `notifyAll()` of the same locked object. Receiver thread is waiting on the locked object, while Sender thread activates the `notifyAll()`.

```
public class MonitorState {

    private static complexObj lock = new complexObj();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writeLog("Main - \tLocker name = " + lock.getName());
        writeLog("Main - \tLocker code = " + lock.getCode());
        try {
            Thread receiver = new Receiver();
            Thread sender = new Sender();

            receiver.start();
            sender.start();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            writeLog("Main - \tLocker name = " + lock.getName());
            writeLog("Main - \tLocker code = " + lock.getCode());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            writeLog(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeLog(String msg) {
        Date time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.S");
        System.out.println(df.format(time) + " " + msg);
    }

    // locking object
    private static class complexObj {
        private String name = "complexObj";
        private Integer code = 0;

        public complexObj() {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Integer getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        public void setCode(Integer code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
    }

    private static class Receiver extends Thread {
        public Receiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int timeout = 100;
            try{
                synchronized (lock) {
                    writeLog("Receiver - Waiting for " + timeout + " ms.");
                    lock.wait(timeout);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                writeLog("Receiver - Interrupted.");
            }
            writeLog("Receiver - Timed out.");
            writeLog("Receiver - Locker code = " + lock.getCode());
            if (lock.getCode() == 0) {
                writeLog("Receiver - Setting values into the locker.");
                lock.setName("Receiver");
                lock.setCode(2);                
            }

        }
    }

    private static class Sender extends Thread {
        public Sender() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    int sleepTime = 3000;
                    writeLog("Sender - \tSleeping for " + sleepTime + " ms.");
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                    writeLog("Sender - \tSetting values into the locker.");
                    lock.setName("Sender");
                    lock.setCode(1);
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    writeLog("Sender - \tInterrupted.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
 16:17:52.191 Main -    Locker name = complexObj
 16:17:52.237 Main -    Locker code = 0
 16:17:52.237 Receiver - Waiting for 4000 ms.
 16:17:52.238 Sender -  Sleeping for 3000 ms.
 16:17:55.238 Sender -  Setting values into the locker.
 16:17:55.238 Receiver - Timed out.
 16:17:55.238 Receiver - Locker code = 1
 16:17:57.237 Main -    Locker name = Sender
 16:17:57.237 Main -    Locker code = 1
```

My question is - why isn't the Receiver reaches to the "*Interrupted*" message?

Second question:
If I change the wait time for the Receiver thread to 100ms, the output is:

```
16:31:21.522 Main -     Locker name = complexObj
16:31:21.571 Main -     Locker code = 0
16:31:21.571 Receiver - Waiting for 100 ms.
16:31:21.571 Sender -   Sleeping for 3000 ms.
16:31:24.572 Sender -   Setting values into the locker.
16:31:24.572 Receiver - Timed out.
16:31:24.572 Receiver - Locker code = 1
16:31:26.571 Main -     Locker name = Sender
16:31:26.571 Main -     Locker code = 1
```

Looking at the timestamp, you see that it took 3 seconds for the Receiver to get to the "Timed out" message, and not 100ms as it should have.
3 seconds is the time the sender is active before using the notifyAll().
Can you please explain why 3 seconds and not 100ms?

Comment: A second question. In the Receiver thread I change the timeout time to 100ms. The output in this case is: 16:31:21.522 Main -  Locker name = complexObj
16:31:21.571 Main -  Locker code = 0
16:31:21.571 Receiver - Waiting for 100 ms.
16:31:21.571 Sender -  Sleeping for 3000 ms.
16:31:24.572 Sender -  Setting values into the locker.
16:31:24.572 Receiver - Timed out.
16:31:24.572 Receiver - Locker code = 1
16:31:26.571 Main -  Locker name = Sender
16:31:26.571 Main -  Locker code = 1. Looking at the timestamp, why did the Receiver waited for 3 seconds and didn't timeout after 100ms?

Comment: if the second question is unrelated, post it as new question, if it is, edit your original question. Reading comment such long is painful experience nobody will bother going through.

Comment: I tried to edit it, but Enter is not working in a comment.    Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't edit comment, edit question.

Comment: thanks, I added the second question into the main question.

Answer (score 1):

When the lock is notified, the method `wait` just returns, no exception is thrown. `InterruptException` is thrown when the thread is interrupted using `Thread.interrupt()`, not when the lock is notified.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the second question - the Sender sleeps for 3 seconds, keeping the lock. If you want a thread to cease execution and release the lock, use wait(3000) instead of sleep(3000).

Comment: wait() won't be useful in my case because the purpose of my tests is to try to simulate IlegalMonitorStateException. I want to see what happens if I lock an object which is not immutable, change it after the timeout and see if this cause the exception. The problem is that I can't get to the timeout before the notifyAll() releases the lock. Then what's the purpose of the timeout if it never times out?

Comment: Correct answer, but it deserves more explanation:  After 100ms, the receiver's `lock.wait()` call times out, but the wait() call can not return until it re-acquires the mutex.  But the mutex is owned by the sender at that time, and the sender doesn't release it until it's run() method is finished.  So there is no way for the wait() call in the receiver thread to return until the sender thread is completely finished.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation helps a lot. Still, I don't get what's the point of waiting on timeout, if the receiver will always continue to wait, even if the timeout has passed, and the wait() and notifyAll() should both be locked and synchronized by the same object? I mean if something bad happens on the function that uses the notifyAll(),the wait() might wait forever even though there's timeout.